# How to disable auto suspend temporary (reset idle time)

Tags: bash, gnome, suspend, power-management, dbus

In Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS(default GNOME desktop). I enable auto suspend on Ubuntu GNOME desktop, but, If only running my program, I want to disable auto suspend.

My program running in a second, and loop many cycle. I maybe found that auto suspend is looking at this value:

```
org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor
```

To stop suspend temporary, I want how to reset this idle time. For example:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

while :
do
  # <anything to reset idle time>  <- I WANT!
  ./myprogram
  sleep 1
done
```

I dont want comletely disable autosuspend.

Do you have a nice command?

Comment: Do you mean disabling suspend on AC power, like with `gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power sleep-inactive-ac-type  "nothing"`, then back to "suspend"?

Comment: If possible, I dont want to change any setting.
This program may stop with Ctrl-C.
So, cannot back to setting.

If reset idle time, It behaves as I want.

Comment: You can't change the settings without changing the settings. You can [`trap` Ctrl+C (SIGINT)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12771964/4970442)

Answer (score 2):

Introspecting the `Mutter.IdleMonitor` shows us there is a method `ResetIdletime`:

```
gdbus introspect --session --dest org.gnome.Shell --object-path /org/gnome/Mutter/IdleMonitor/Core
...
   interface org.gnome.Mutter.IdleMonitor {
     methods:
    GetIdletime(out t idletime);
    AddIdleWatch(in  t interval, out u id);
    AddUserActiveWatch(out u id);
    RemoveWatch(in  u id);
    ResetIdletime();
```

Unfortunately, the gnome developers decided to keep its use to themselves, see [meta-idle-monitor-dbus.c](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/mutter/-/blob/master/src/backends/meta-idle-monitor-dbus.c#L49):

```C
 handle_reset_idletime (...) ...
  if (!g_getenv ("MUTTER_DEBUG_RESET_IDLETIME"))
  ...
   "This method is for testing purposes only. MUTTER_DEBUG_RESET_IDLETIME
    must be set to use it");
```

Perhaps you could find out how to set this debug variable in your gnome environment.

---

One other possibility is to use systemd's inhibit mechanism. This allows you to prefix a command with a request to inhibit various actions, such as shutdown, sleep, and idle, whilst it runs.

```bsh
$ systemd-inhibit --mode=block --what=sleep --why='for me'  sleep 100 &
$ systemd-inhibit --list
   ...
    Who: sleep 100 (UID 1000/meuh, PID 3262/systemd-inhibit)
   What: sleep
    Why: for me
   Mode: block
```

Use this to call your shell script, and you can still interrupt it.
See `man systemd-inhibit`.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you some information!

Finaly, I solved it by input null key with `xdotool`.

`xdotool key 0x00`

I can reset idle-time simply.

Comment: thank you for such simple hint, it saved my time!
However sending a key 0x00 causes freezes in my system, some complaints from gnome-shell in logs, so I'd suggest a bit safer approach: 
`xdotool mousemove 0 0 mousemove restore`

Answer (score 1):

For the desktop, there is also the tool caffeine, or the follow-up [caffeine-ng](https://codeberg.org/WhyNotHugo/caffeine-ng).